# Create Folders based on 6th number in file name, create a folder and move file into that folder

Tags: batch-file

First time poster and "very" limited experience.  I have been tasked with taking PDF's (about 100,000+-) and sorting them.  The file name is 123456700.PDF  I would like to separate these files into folders no larger than 5,000 files.  So depending on the 6th number in the file name, I would like to create a folder 123455000 (if 6th number is equal to or greater than 5) and 123450000 (if the 6th number is less than 5).  Then I would like to move that file into the folder that was just created.  I would like a Batch/Script File that could be ran on a selected folder that would accomplish this task.  Thanks in advance for all replies!!

Comment: We need a bit more specifics. Are all file names the same length or is there variable length. For instance, will the 6th character always be the one we want so we can just index easily?

Comment: Yes all file names will be the same length and the 6th character will be the deciding number for folder creation.

Comment: Could you clearly define if the folders are being created at 5000 files maximum or just the number at the sixth character! As you have already stated more than 100000 files exist and the file names are the same length, only 9999 files would fit your scenario and therefore only two folders would be needed. _What happens to the other 90000+ files?_

Comment: I have roughly 100,000 files (all named XXXXXXXXX.pdf)  These 9 characters are numbers 0-9.  All I need is the 6th character as the identifier to see if the folder created will be xxxxx0000 or xxxxx5000.  This way no more than 5000 files will be in a single folder. And move that file into the folder that was just created.  The other 90,000+ files would have their own folder depending of what the first 5 number are.  Ex.(456875000 or 695741000).  I hope that makes sense.  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: There are methods for defining/counting the number of moved files without reading characters in a string. What makes sense to me is that you're asking a part question. Many people will take a look, spend time and attempt to help. As soon as you receive a part answer to your part question, you'll post again asking about the rest of the task. This is not fair on those helping and not the proper way to conduct your business here.

Comment: I'm not sure how to take your answer.  I do not see this as a part of a question or task.  I gave as much information as I can.  The counting/defining of moved files is not the issue.  The issue is simply looking at the 6th number in a filename and creating a folder of xxxxx0000 or xxxxx5000 and then moving said file into that folder.  This will repeat for all files in directory.  Task complete.  This is my first post on this site and I explained about my lack of experience.  So, I do not see how that is unfair or an improper way to conduct business, but if I offended you I apologize.

Comment: What have you tried on your own, where are you stuck? This is not a free code writing service, so please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
CD /D "X:\path\to\pdfs"
For %%A in (*.pdf) Do (
  Set "Filename=%%~nA"
  If !FileName:~5,1! lss 5 (
    Set Folder=!FileName:~0,5!0000
  ) Else (
    Set Folder=!FileName:~0,5!5000
  )
  If not Exist "%Folder%" MkDir "%Folder%"
  Move %%A "%Folder%"
)
```

**Edit** substring position is zero based, had to change offset.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to LotPings answer:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "SrcDir=C:\Users\AName\Documents"
Set "DstDir=C:\Users\AName\Documents\PDFs"

If Not Exist "%SrcDir%\*.pdf" Exit/B

For %%A In ("%SrcDir%\*.pdf") Do (Set "FName=%%~nA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If !FName:~-4! Lss 5000 (Set DstNum=0000) Else Set "DstNum=5000"
    If Not Exist "%DstDir%\!FName:~,-4!!DstNum!\" (
        MD "%DstDir%\!FName:~,-4!!DstNum!")
    Move "%%~A" "%DstDir%\!FName:~,-4!!DstNum!"
    EndLocal)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to try and give this a crack, though I do not generally work with batch, but I can at least get you going...

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do {
  set TEMP = %f:5%
  if exists <your path>/%TEMP% <do nothing>
  if not exists <your path>/%TEMP% mkdir <your path>/%TEMP%
  <move file to this new directory
}
```

This isn't entirely working/correct, but it should give you a good idea of what to do.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be in Batch (I just thought that would be the easiest).  Thank you for the quick response!